# Fast edit of Excel file

Tags: java, performance, excel

I have this code to edit certain cells in my Excel file using Apache POI, but it is really slow. How can I improved the performance?

Ideally I would like to edit 20000 rows in less than one minute. At the moment it does ~100/min. Any suggestions would be great.

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, InvalidFormatException{
        InputStream inp = new FileInputStream("test.xls");
        FileOutputStream fileOut = new FileOutputStream("edited-test.xls");
        Workbook wb = WorkbookFactory.create(inp);
        Sheet sheet = wb.getSheetAt(0);
        for(int i=2;i <20002;i++){
            Row row = sheet.getRow(i);

            Cell cell4 = row.getCell(4); 
            cell4.setCellValue(i); 

            Cell cell6 = row.getCell(6);
            cell6.setCellValue("aa"+i); 

            Cell cell8 = row.getCell(8); 
            cell8.setCellValue("2"); 

            wb.write(fileOut);
            System.out.println(i);
        }
        fileOut.close();
        System.out.println("Done!");
    }
```

Comment: Keep in mind that `System.out.println(i)` could slow your application. If you don't need it, I would suggest you to remove it.

Comment: @Marc-Andre good to know, i had it there so i could see how quickly each row was processed.

Comment: It's not always decisive, but it could help. Try to execute the code by removing it and try with it to see if it does indeed make a difference.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

First thing you should do is only write the file out once, not 20,000 times ;-)

Move the `wb.write(fileOut);` to be outside the loop.....

Additionally, there may be some improvement by reversing the loop:

```
for(int i=2;i <20002;i++){
```

can become:

```
for(int i=20001;i >= 2;i--){
```

This may make some memory management in the API faster.

Comment: How would reversing the loop help?

Comment: because often data structures are incrementally extended, and starting from the largest member and working backwards **may** mean that only one large allocation is done, instead of multiple smaller ones as the data set grows.

Answer (score 1):

Replace:

```
cell6.setCellValue("aa"+i);
```

with:

```
cell6.setCellValue(aa.append(i).toString());
aa.setLength(2); // cut the StringBuilder to just "aa", keeping it's original capacity
```

and the write the following two lines before the for:

```
StringBuilder aa = new StringBuilder(7); // length of "aa" plus 5 digits for max value of the loop index
aa.append("aa");
```

-- Edited to add capacity optimization and use setLength() per comments.

Comment: I am not 100 % but this probably what already happening when the code is compiled.

Comment: Agree with @Marc-Andre - but, an interesting observation, and worth noting that moving the `new StringBuilder()` outside the loop, and then reusing it with a `aa.setLength(0);` may have a small benefit.

Comment: @rolfl As I said, I'm not that good in optimization, but maybe using `setLength()` would not help that much http://stackoverflow.com/a/5193094/2115680 .

Comment: I guess this string could be constructed with a array of chars[7], and then updating just the digit(s) that changed in the loop, but unfortunately I don't have time right now to build the full example. Sorry :P